# How to filter row if all tokens in column contains any from stop words list in python?

Tags: python, dataframe

Let say I have a Dataframe:

```
Sentences              Group
It is you                0
She likes flower         1
She hates gardening      2
```

and a stop list:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop_words = stopwords.words('english')
```

How to drop row if all tokens/words in column `df['Sentences']` contains any from `stop_words` list. Hence, my result supposed to be like this:

```
Sentences              Group
She likes flower         1
She hates gardening      2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split your column with spaces and then compare lists :

```
df = df[~df['Sentences'].apply(lambda r: list(set(r.split(' ')).intersection(stop_words))!=[] )]
```

The `~` means 'does not contain' following lines.

Comment: It solved my problem if df['Sentences'] contains only one word. Or do I need to split the sentence in df['Sentences'] first and compare with stop_words?

Comment: You're true I changed the anwer

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```
filtered_df = df[~df['Sentences'].str.split().apply(lambda x: any(s for s in x if s in stop_words))]
```

First splitting the sentence. Then checking if any of the words in the sentence is also in your `stop_words`. If a word is in there `any` will return True. We reverse that with `~`.